# Docker container stops immediately

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker from the beginning and when I'm trying to start a container it seems to stop immediately. Here is my cmd.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior.
You're just creating a python container and running without giving it anything to do so it just exits.

---

If you just want to run a file in python container then you can use:

```
docker run --name container_name python:3.10.8 python /path/to/<filename>.py
```

---

If you want to run a project you can [mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) the project directory and use docker exec command to run the main file:

```
docker create --name container_name -v /path/to/local/directory:/app python:3.10.8
docker exec container_name python /app/<filename>.py
```

---

However, you should consider creating a `Dockerfile` and [building the python image](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/) and then [run your image as container](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/run-containers/).

Some other useful references: 
 [How to Run a Python Script using Docker?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-a-python-script-using-docker/) 
[How to “Dockerize” Your Python Applications](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-dockerize-your-python-applications/)